# How to defer order creation in magento until a particular date ? (standing order)

Tags: php, magento

How to defer order creation in magento until a particular date ?
This is something like a standing order ( where the order is placed and the fulfillment (order creation, payment, shipping etc) happens at regular intervals ( start of a particular season).
Is this possible in magento ?

To explain further,

User can place a  standing order. It will not be displayed in the order list or anywhere..only the Standing Orders menu will list those orders. There will not be any magento order created either.

Upon the start of the season (summer, winter etc..), the order is really created (magento order created), the invoice sent, orders fulfilled etc.. (Only now the real magento order created).

How to achieve this kind of deferred order placement in magento. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the whole "order creation mechanism" (after payment is successfull)  by a mechanism such as :

- create a new boolean quote attribute "orderable"
- at the end of the checkout just value this boolean to "true" and save quote without creating any order
- set a new empty quote objet to the user session
- create a new shell script fired by CRON that will create your order based on all your quote that have an "orerable" attribute to True

Code to do all that is easily found by analysing standard code.